# How does android kill app processes when zygote dies?

Tags: android

After `adb shell stop` or `adb shell busybox pkill zygote`, I notice that all of the android app processes like `com.android.email` disappear, How is it done?

Comment: What do you mean how is it done? Zygote is the parent of all application processes. It literally runs all Apps which is also the reason why Zygote tends to show up in most stack traces. If you kill Zygote then all application processes die with it.

Comment: If you had spent 5 seconds on Google reading about Zygote you would have figured that out by yourself.

Answer (score -1):

`adb shell busybox ps -o pid,ppid,pgid,comm` shows that all of the app processes belongs to the same process group, and the group leader is `zygote`, that's why `pkill zygote` will kill all the app processes.

`dex2oat` for boot.oat is also forked from zygote but not belonging to the zygote process group. if you purge the dalvik-cache and `adb shell stop; adb shell start` several times, you will see several `dex2oat` processes running concurrently, and this will result in an OOM error.